# Want to use both older and newer version of ant plugin in eclipse for two different projects

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to use two versions of ant plugin in eclipse for two different projects. Both versions are available in the plugins folder of my Eclipse. But I'm able to see only the latest version of ant plug-in when I'm trying to add it in the plug-in dependencies in Manifest.MF file. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to import both of ant plug-ins into your Eclipse workspace. Then you can let your projects depend on any version of ant for your development.

For building or releasing process, you can use Tycho to define a target platform to include both of them.